# Wix Burn install .Net 4.5.1 only if installed .Net version is lower and not higher

Tags: .net, installation, wix, burn

We have .Net 4.5.1 as pre-requisite for our software suite. At the time when we authored burn, we had .net 4.5.1 as the latest version and so we didn't had to check for higher version installations. Now that we have 4.6.X or higher .Net versions available in the pc, our setup is always trying to install .Net 4.5.1. So, how to check if higher versions are installed and skip .Net installation?

We don't use web install. The setup file will be available as a .exe for burn to access. Here is the current authoring code.

```
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="Netfx451Full" />
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="$(var.NetFx40EulaLink)" />

<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version"
                     Variable="Net4FullVersion" />
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version"
                     Variable="Net4x64FullVersion" Win64="yes" />

<PackageGroup Id="Netfx451Full">
  <ExePackage Id="Net45" Name="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1.exe"
              Description="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 AllOS (x86 and x64) Setup"
              Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
              InstallCommand="/norestart"
              SourceFile="$(var.PreRequisites_x86)DotNetFramework\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
              DetectCondition="(Net4FullVersion = &quot;4.5.50938&quot;) AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Net4x64FullVersion = &quot;4.5.50938&quot;))"
              InstallCondition="(VersionNT >= v6.1 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.1) AND (NOT (Net4FullVersion = &quot;4.5.50938&quot; OR Net4x64FullVersion = &quot;4.5.50938&quot;))" />
</PackageGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the functionality made in **WixNetFxExtension**: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html

Also look at this:
[Installing .NET redistributable with Wix Bootstrapper (Burn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099486/installing-net-redistributable-with-wix-bootstrapper-burn)

Just add this (no conditions needed):

```
<Chain>
    <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx451Redist" />
    <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.AppInstaller.TargetPath)" />
</Chain>
```

Comment: Yeah I know this. But my problem is I have a higher version installed in the system. And I don't know how to change the install condition in that case.

Comment: Try using this value: WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_451_OR_LATER_INSTALLED (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html)

Answer (score 2):

You really should use the [builtin packages](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html).  If not, at least base the conditions off of [their source code](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib):

```
<?define NetFx451MinRelease = 378675 ?>

...

<Fragment> 
  <util:RegistrySearchRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/> 

  ...

  <WixVariable Id="NetFx451WebDetectCondition"
               Value="NETFRAMEWORK45 &gt;= $(var.NetFx451MinRelease)"
               Overridable="yes" />

  ...

  DetectCondition="!(wix.NetFx451WebDetectCondition)"
```